# How does angular work with the node in an Ionic app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework

I am trying to make an ionic app with angularjs in the front end and node.js in the back end.

I get the front end part and I have done it in angularjs. But I am not sure how to work with node.js as a back end.

For example I need to make a GET request to a web api with nodejs and use angular to show it in my view. How to make the request with node.js and send it to the angular controller.

I was searching online but I did not see any example or tutorial that could show how angular and node work together.

Any website, tutorial or code snippet in this regard will be very helpful

Answer (score 1):

NodeJS would just act like any server, so you would need to have some end point that returns some data which you should be able to view in your browser via a url. This is the url you would use in your get request from angularjs. See  [this tutorial for how to implement nodejs as your web server](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/node-js-server-side-javascript/)

Comment: I want to make a GET request to a web API online to get some data.
I could also do that with $http in angular, but in my case I want to do it from node.js.
I am confused in the part that of the connection between node and angular.js. Where to add the node.js file and how to make them communicate with angular. I am more concerned on the structure of the project

Comment: You do not need nodejs for that. Nodejs does not ship with your angular application, it is a development tool that can be programmed as a serverside platform, just like php

Comment: @Besa `$http` and `node` are not interchangeable ... they run in completely different environments -- server vs browser

Comment: Yes I need to use nodejsin the server side . Check this :
https://erikberg.com/api/examples/nodejs
I want to get the data as in this example and show them using angular js in my browser

Comment: @Besa So if I understand you, you want your nodejs application to connect to a different server to get some data and then pass that data back to your angularjs application?

Comment: Yes exactly. I can do that with c# as a back end. Can I do that with nodejs

Comment: Did you ever figure out the solution to this?